# bashrc shortcuts in Tmux

Tags: bash, environment-variables, bashrc, tmux

I have sets many shortcuts in `.bashrc` profile of local user, and they work properly. Currently on my 12.04 system but when ever I tried to used them in `tmux`, I always get the same response `command not found`. Is their any extra files which I have to edit for those shortcuts to work on `tmux` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user-specific configuration file should be located at `~/.tmux.conf`, while a global configuration file should be located at `/etc/tmux.conf`. Default configuration files can be found in `/usr/share/tmux/`.

Edit the `~/.tmux.conf` file to include whatever shortcuts you want on tmux

Key bindings may be changed with the bind and unbind commands in tmux.conf.

For example, you can change the prefix key `(i.e. Ctrl-b)` to `Ctrl-a` by adding the following commands in your `~/.tmux.conf` configuration file:

```
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-a
bind a send-prefix
```

Another example:

To use `PgUp` and `PgDown`, to switch windows in tmux:

```
bind -n PageUp previous-window
bind -n PageDown next-window
```